# How to open mail within the app from webview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, ios6

This is my code..

```
if ([ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"mailto" ])

 {

        MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
            NSString *strEmail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",requestURL];
            NSString *subString = [[strEmail componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] lastObject];
            [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:subString, nil]];
            [composer setSubject:@"Kreativ-Q"];
            [composer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:YES];
            [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
            [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
            [composer release];
        }
    }
```

But when i click on the link in webview it is opening in mailBox. and when i send or cancel the mail from there and go back to my app the mail was still there. They show me twice. I just want, it would open in my app only..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the NSLog of [ requestURL scheme ]

Comment: Why do not you create the composer object after checking the condition ** if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) ** and I will recommend to show the message if mail is not configured.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking to open/read emails from within your app. MFMailComposeViewController is intended to compose and send new emails, and will not read received email.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 it is "mailto". It is going in successfully but the mail opens twice. in mailbox also.. at that time the app went into the background and when i come back to app the mailcontroller is opened.

Comment: May be this condition is calling twice.. just make breakpoint in this code

Comment: Yea.. I resolved the problem.I need to write return NO at last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May help you:

Set this delegate in your .h file if you didnt.

```
<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```